# Parse String to Array or DataTable

Tags: vb.net, arrays, string, parsing

I'm trying to parse a long boring text document and parse and format it.

```
"7/29/2012 1:25:20 PM","Summary Plan/Second Floor /Master_VAV_2-24","Source :OEnd"
"7/29/2012 11:25:23 AM","Summary Plan/Second Floor /Master_VAV_2-24","Source :OStart"
```

I'd like to parse each value between the quotes but I cant find anything online to help me, I believe it's a matter of knowing what to call it and search for.

"date", "location", "type" would be the 3 values I want to parse it into, then I could run a loop for each item in datatable and format it as required.

***ANY HELP*** would be great, thank you!

I'm thinking of using RegEx to get the rows and add them manually to an array, something like this.

```
Dim rx As New Regex(",", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Multiline)
Dim matches As MatchCollection = rx.Matches(strSource)
For Each match As Match In matches
Dim matchValue As String = match.Value
If Not list.Contains(matchValue) Then
    list.Add(matchValue)
End If
Next
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This format appears to be CSV - use one of the many free and open source CSV parsers (google ".NET CSV parser" will return many results.

There is one that comes built in, in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` namespece - the [`TextFieldParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx).